# How can I iterate through all the properties of a Microsoft Project Task?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

MS Project has a task Object, with literally hundreds of properties. Example, start date, end date, baseline1Start through to Baseline10Start, and so on.

My pseudo code would be

```
dim tsk as Task
set tsk = MSProj.ActiveProject.Tasks.Item(1)

For Each taskPropertyin tsk.properties. 
     debug.print taskproperty
Next taskProperty
```

... but I cannot find a collection of task properties. They seem to all be explicitly named, and I would have to refer to each of them individually.

[Loop through all TableFields in Microsoft Project add to combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51144134/loop-through-all-tablefields-in-microsoft-project-add-to-combobox)

This post reveals some of inner workings, but the it's limited to the properties / attributes that are visible only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through each field for MS Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32209245/loop-through-each-field-for-ms-project)